# Avoiding duplicate methods for Task and Task<T>

Tags: c#, .net, task

I have some logic for `Task` and `Task<T>`. 
Is there any way to avoid duplicating code ?

My current code is following:

```
public async Task<SocialNetworkUserInfo> GetMe()
{
    return await WrapException(() => new SocialNetworkUserInfo());
}

public async Task AuthenticateAsync()
{
    await WrapException(() => _facebook.Authenticate());
}

public async Task<T> WrapException<T>(Func<Task<T>> task)
{
    try
    {
        return await task();
    }
    catch (FacebookNoInternetException ex)
    {
        throw new NoResponseException(ex.Message, ex, true);
    }
    catch (FacebookException ex)
    {
        throw new SocialNetworkException("Social network call failed", ex);
    }
}

public async Task WrapException(Func<Task> task)
{
    try
    {
        await task();
    }
    catch (FacebookNoInternetException ex)
    {
        throw new NoResponseException(ex.Message, ex, true);
    }
    catch (FacebookException ex)
    {
        throw new SocialNetworkException("Social network call failed", ex);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make the `Task` overload call the other one, and return a dummy value.

```
public async Task WrapException(Func<Task> task)
{
    await WrapException<object>(async () => {
        await task();
        return null;
    });
}
```

Or, since the `async` keyword is unnecessary here:

```
public Task WrapException(Func<Task> task)
{
    return WrapException<object>(async () => {
        await task();
        return null;
    });
}
```

Comment: While this is possible, the overhead added, combined with the fact that `Task` related code is often performance sensitive code, means that while this is possible, it's usually not a good idea in practice  for production code.

Comment: @Servy Strange, I'd've thought that the IO delay of network access would dwarf any overhead from this simple `async` lambda. Still, if you can find that there's significant time being wasted here, you can (worst case) duplicate the code, like the original post had. If you have a better way to do this, I (and Grigory, I'm sure) would be glad to hear it.

Comment: @TimS. That's just it, there are several purposes for using tasks.  There's their uses in network IO and the like, in which the overhead here is no problem, and then there's their use in CPU intensive multithreaded code, in which it *would* be a noticable overhead.  Since most general purpose task related methods don't know which type of tasks they'll be working with, they need to be designed to work efficiently with either.  I don't know of any particularly good method of addressing this barring duplication.

Comment: @Servy Ok, good point! Still, this particular method is catching `Facebook..Exception`s, so it's clear that it's used in network IO-related tasks.

Comment: @TimS. Yeah, which is why I don't have a problem with it here; the comment is more for readers who may be considering applying this technique to their own situations which may not involve Facebook.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `Func` does not itself throw, the following would work.

```
public async Task<T> WrapException<T>(Func<Task<T>> task)
{
    var actualTask = task();
    await WrapException((Task)actualTask);
    return actualTask.Result;
}
```

We know that `Result` won't block or throw since `WrapException` ensured it ran to completion.

Comment: Thanks for quick answer! The sad thing about this code is that any exception thrown before actual asyncronous stuff begins, will be thrown before await. And exception wont get to actual WrapException method.